# SVG CSS Multiple animations

Tags: css, svg

I have created a treasure map animation, first, it will display the path in light grey but as animation begins I would like the light grey dashes to disappear or turn to a black color as the fill animation ".road" kicks in. I am struggling to get the light grey dashes ".steps" to disappear as the fill animations go over that position.

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.road {
  stroke-dasharray: 744;
  stroke-dashoffset: -744;
  animation: draw-road 10s infinite;
}

.steps {
  stroke-dasharray: -744;
  stroke-dashoffset: 744;
  animation: draw-steps 10s reverse;
}

@keyframes draw-road {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 744;
    stroke: #000000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke: #000000;
  }
}

@keyframes draw-steps {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <style>
        .st0{fill:none;stroke:#999;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10}.st2{fill:#b3b3b3}
      </style>
      <g id="Layer_1">
        <path class="st0" d="M20.82 225.01c1.05-1.32 2.08-2.63 3.1-3.92"/>
        <path d="M30.16 213.14c47.85-61.32 61-85.9 56.16-90.62-7.14-6.97-60.04 22.79-57 46 2.94 22.48 115.32-.75 124 27 3.14 10.05-9.18 19.09-5 25 8.54 12.09 73.6-6.39 76-30 3.26-32.1-111.39-53.93-109-82 1.2-14.1 32-30.41 153.49-42.53" fill="none" class="road" stroke="#999" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="10.1073,10.1073"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M20.82 225.01c1.05-1.32 2.08-2.63 3.1-3.92"/>
        <path d="M30.16 213.14c47.85-61.32 61-85.9 56.16-90.62-7.14-6.97-60.04 22.79-57 46 2.94 22.48 115.32-.75 124 27 3.14 10.05-9.18 19.09-5 25 8.54 12.09 73.6-6.39 76-30 3.26-32.1-111.39-53.93-109-82 1.2-14.1 32-30.41 153.49-42.53" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="10.1073,10.1073" class="steps"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M273.84 65.49c1.64-.16 3.3-.32 4.98-.48"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M55.96 140.02l-3.27-4.42-4.42 3.27-1.79-2.41 4.42-3.27-3.27-4.42 2.41-1.79 3.27 4.42 4.42-3.27 1.79 2.41-4.42 3.27 3.27 4.42-2.41 1.79zM158 200.86l-4.29-3.44-3.44 4.29-2.34-1.88 3.44-4.29-4.29-3.44 1.88-2.34 4.29 3.44 3.44-4.29 2.34 1.88-3.44 4.29 4.29 3.44-1.88 2.34zM149 140.86l-4.29-3.44-3.44 4.29-2.34-1.88 3.44-4.29-4.29-3.44 1.88-2.34 4.29 3.44 3.44-4.29 2.34 1.88-3.44 4.29 4.29 3.44-1.88 2.34zM212 78.86l-4.29-3.44-3.44 4.29-2.34-1.88 3.44-4.29-4.29-3.44 1.88-2.34 4.29 3.44 3.44-4.29 2.34 1.88-3.44 4.29 4.29 3.44-1.88 2.34z"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Move the path `class="road"` at the end of the group.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution using CSS

```css
svg{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
} 

.road{
  fill:none;
  stroke:black;
  stroke-dasharray:10 10;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  stroke-width:2;
}
.steps{
   fill:none;
   stroke:#999;
  stroke-dasharray:10 10;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  stroke-width:2;
  mask:url(#msk1);
      }


#stepMask{
   fill:none;
   stroke:black;
   stroke-width:2;
   stroke-dashoffset: 744;
   stroke-dasharray:744,744;
   animation: draw-steps 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes draw-steps {
100% {stroke-dashoffset:0;}
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#999;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10}.st2{fill:#b3b3b3}
  </style>
    <defs>
    <mask id="msk1">
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <path id="stepMask"  d="M30.16 213.14c47.85-61.32 61-85.9 56.16-90.62-7.14-6.97-60.04 22.79-57 46 2.94 22.48 115.32-.75 124 27 3.14 10.05-9.18 19.09-5 25 8.54 12.09 73.6-6.39 76-30 3.26-32.1-111.39-53.93-109-82 1.2-14.1 32-30.41 153.49-42.53" />
     
    </mask>
 </defs>
  <g id="Layer_1">
     <path class="road" d="M30.16 213.14c47.85-61.32 61-85.9 56.16-90.62-7.14-6.97-60.04 22.79-57 46 2.94 22.48 115.32-.75 124 27 3.14 10.05-9.18 19.09-5 25 8.54 12.09 73.6-6.39 76-30 3.26-32.1-111.39-53.93-109-82 1.2-14.1 32-30.41 153.49-42.53" />
     <path class="steps"  d="M30.16 213.14c47.85-61.32 61-85.9 56.16-90.62-7.14-6.97-60.04 22.79-57 46 2.94 22.48 115.32-.75 124 27 3.14 10.05-9.18 19.09-5 25 8.54 12.09 73.6-6.39 76-30 3.26-32.1-111.39-53.93-109-82 1.2-14.1 32-30.41 153.49-42.53" />
   <path class="st2" d="M55.96 140.02l-3.27-4.42-4.42 3.27-1.79-2.41 4.42-3.27-3.27-4.42 2.41-1.79 3.27 4.42 4.42-3.27 1.79 2.41-4.42 3.27 3.27 4.42-2.41 1.79zM158 200.86l-4.29-3.44-3.44 4.29-2.34-1.88 3.44-4.29-4.29-3.44 1.88-2.34 4.29 3.44 3.44-4.29 2.34 1.88-3.44 4.29 4.29 3.44-1.88 2.34zM149 140.86l-4.29-3.44-3.44 4.29-2.34-1.88 3.44-4.29-4.29-3.44 1.88-2.34 4.29 3.44 3.44-4.29 2.34 1.88-3.44 4.29 4.29 3.44-1.88 2.34zM212 78.86l-4.29-3.44-3.44 4.29-2.34-1.88 3.44-4.29-4.29-3.44 1.88-2.34 4.29 3.44 3.44-4.29 2.34 1.88-3.44 4.29 4.29 3.44-1.88 2.34z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Solution using SVG mask.

- Below is a black line `class="road"`
- Above is a gray line `class="steps"`
- A mask is applied to the gray line which, when moving, erases the
  gray line showing the black line

This creates the effect of filling the gray line with black

```css
svg{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
} 

.road{
  fill:none;
  stroke:black;
  stroke-dasharray:10 10;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  stroke-width:2;
}
.steps{
   fill:none;
   stroke:#999;
  stroke-dasharray:10 10;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  stroke-width:2;
  animation: draw-steps 10s reverse;
  
}

#stepMask{
   fill:none;
   stroke:black;
   stroke-width:2;
   stroke-dashoffset: 744;
   stroke-dasharray:744,744;
 
  
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#999;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10}.st2{fill:#b3b3b3}
  </style>
    <defs>
    <mask id="msk1">
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <path id="stepMask"  d="M30.16 213.14c47.85-61.32 61-85.9 56.16-90.62-7.14-6.97-60.04 22.79-57 46 2.94 22.48 115.32-.75 124 27 3.14 10.05-9.18 19.09-5 25 8.54 12.09 73.6-6.39 76-30 3.26-32.1-111.39-53.93-109-82 1.2-14.1 32-30.41 153.49-42.53" >
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="20s" values="744;0;744" repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
    </path> 
    </mask>
 </defs>
  <g id="Layer_1">
   
   <path class="road" d="M30.16 213.14c47.85-61.32 61-85.9 56.16-90.62-7.14-6.97-60.04 22.79-57 46 2.94 22.48 115.32-.75 124 27 3.14 10.05-9.18 19.09-5 25 8.54 12.09 73.6-6.39 76-30 3.26-32.1-111.39-53.93-109-82 1.2-14.1 32-30.41 153.49-42.53" />
  
   <path class="steps" mask="url(#msk1)" d="M30.16 213.14c47.85-61.32 61-85.9 56.16-90.62-7.14-6.97-60.04 22.79-57 46 2.94 22.48 115.32-.75 124 27 3.14 10.05-9.18 19.09-5 25 8.54 12.09 73.6-6.39 76-30 3.26-32.1-111.39-53.93-109-82 1.2-14.1 32-30.41 153.49-42.53" />
   
  <path class="st2" d="M55.96 140.02l-3.27-4.42-4.42 3.27-1.79-2.41 4.42-3.27-3.27-4.42 2.41-1.79 3.27 4.42 4.42-3.27 1.79 2.41-4.42 3.27 3.27 4.42-2.41 1.79zM158 200.86l-4.29-3.44-3.44 4.29-2.34-1.88 3.44-4.29-4.29-3.44 1.88-2.34 4.29 3.44 3.44-4.29 2.34 1.88-3.44 4.29 4.29 3.44-1.88 2.34zM149 140.86l-4.29-3.44-3.44 4.29-2.34-1.88 3.44-4.29-4.29-3.44 1.88-2.34 4.29 3.44 3.44-4.29 2.34 1.88-3.44 4.29 4.29 3.44-1.88 2.34zM212 78.86l-4.29-3.44-3.44 4.29-2.34-1.88 3.44-4.29-4.29-3.44 1.88-2.34 4.29 3.44 3.44-4.29 2.34 1.88-3.44 4.29 4.29 3.44-1.88 2.34z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Treasure seeker animation on the road**

[image]

The author will probably want to add a map or landscape below the treasure hunt route. 
For the route and image to be adaptive, and the layout not to be violated when changing the screen resolution, you need to add the image inside SVG

`<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncK6A.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />`

I added an animated figure of a man walking along the road

```
<use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(2.5)" style="stroke:#990E0E; fill:black;"> 
    <animateMotion id="an2"
      begin="0s"
      dur="40s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"  >
         <mpath xlink:href="#steps"/>
    </animateMotion>    

   </use>
```

Coordination of the road coloring animation and the human movement animation is achieved by the same time duration of both animations.

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
svg{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
 
} 

.road{
  fill:none;
  stroke:blue;
  stroke-dasharray:12 10;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  stroke-width:3;
}
#steps{
   fill:none;
   stroke:white;
  stroke-dasharray:12 10;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  stroke-width:3;
   
}

#stepMask{
   fill:none;
   stroke:black;
   stroke-width:3;
   stroke-dashoffset: 1887;
   stroke-dasharray:1887,1887;
 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   viewBox="0 0 1200 890" >
  
    <defs>
    <mask id="msk1">
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <path id="stepMask"  d="m398.8 299.8c0 0 70.7-30.6 108.4-33.9 44.2-3.9 88.7 7.5 132 17 73.3 16 144.1 42.3 215 66.9 22.3 7.8 45.8 13.2 66 25.5 14.7 8.9 32.8 17.8 38.7 33.9 5.1 14-6.6 29.4-6.6 44.3 0.1 76 68.8 157.8 33.9 225.3-25.2 48.8-97.9 50-147.1 74.5-32.6 16.2-62.8 38.9-98.1 48.1-34.1 8.9-70.4 6.9-105.6 5.7-72.5-2.5-163.4 23.6-215.9-26.4-31.9-30.3-9.5-88.1-22.6-130.1-8-25.8-9.6-61.8-33.9-73.5-54.1-26.2-175.4 42.4-175.4 42.4" >
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="40s" values="1887;0" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
    </path> 
    </mask> 
     <g id="Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1,-1)">
    <path   fill="none">
         <animate
          attributeName="d"
          begin="0s"
          dur="0.4s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path> 
   </g> 
 </defs> 
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmr13.jpg"
  width="100%" height="100%" />
  <g id="Layer_1">
   
   <path class="road" d="m398.8 299.8c0 0 70.7-30.6 108.4-33.9 44.2-3.9 88.7 7.5 132 17 73.3 16 144.1 42.3 215 66.9 22.3 7.8 45.8 13.2 66 25.5 14.7 8.9 32.8 17.8 38.7 33.9 5.1 14-6.6 29.4-6.6 44.3 0.1 76 68.8 157.8 33.9 225.3-25.2 48.8-97.9 50-147.1 74.5-32.6 16.2-62.8 38.9-98.1 48.1-34.1 8.9-70.4 6.9-105.6 5.7-72.5-2.5-163.4 23.6-215.9-26.4-31.9-30.3-9.5-88.1-22.6-130.1-8-25.8-9.6-61.8-33.9-73.5-54.1-26.2-175.4 42.4-175.4 42.4" />
   <path id="steps" mask="url(#msk1)" d="m398.8 299.8c0 0 70.7-30.6 108.4-33.9 44.2-3.9 88.7 7.5 132 17 73.3 16 144.1 42.3 215 66.9 22.3 7.8 45.8 13.2 66 25.5 14.7 8.9 32.8 17.8 38.7 33.9 5.1 14-6.6 29.4-6.6 44.3 0.1 76 68.8 157.8 33.9 225.3-25.2 48.8-97.9 50-147.1 74.5-32.6 16.2-62.8 38.9-98.1 48.1-34.1 8.9-70.4 6.9-105.6 5.7-72.5-2.5-163.4 23.6-215.9-26.4-31.9-30.3-9.5-88.1-22.6-130.1-8-25.8-9.6-61.8-33.9-73.5-54.1-26.2-175.4 42.4-175.4 42.4" />
   
  
  </g>  
  
    <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(2.5)" style="stroke:blue; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an2"
       begin="0s"
       dur="40s"
       repeatCount="1"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#steps"/>
     </animateMotion>  

 </use> 
</svg>
</div>
```